# Linux password reset through Grub menu doesn't work

Tags: linux, password, grub, xubuntu

when i try to reset my root password through the grub menu I get the prompt:

**root@(none):/#**

If i wait to long, like 4 seconds, I get the message:

**[    15.011870]random: crng init done**

**[    15.011924]random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting**

and I cannot type and retype my password fast enough to be able to finish, and when I am, and it says:

**passwd: password updated successfully**

but it still doesn't update the password, even though it says it did.

For the record, my path to get there is get to the grub menu, go to "advanced options for Ununtu" then press 'e' on "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-70-generic, then I delete **ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff** and replace it with **rw init=/bin/bash** on the line that starts with Linux. after that I hit f10 and get the prompt where the problem starts)

Why can't i reset my root password, what am i doing wrong? is it with the system? I am running Xubutu on a 2007 Dell Inspiron 1520 laptop.

Comment: You can also try to replace the line with 'text single' and try your luck again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sync` to save your changes to disk before you reboot. Normally, this is handled for you when you reboot, but when you use `init=/bin/bash`, the processes that normally do that don't get a chance to run.

Also, regarding this:

> If i wait to long, like 4 seconds, I get the message:
>
> **[ 15.011870]random: crng init done**
>
> **[ 15.011924]random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting**
>
> and I cannot type and retype my password fast enough to be able to
>   finish

Just pretend you don't see those. You can just keep typing as if they didn't appear.